# How to add a class to a fixedcolumn

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using the Datatables jquery plugin and have a table with a fixed column:

```
 new $.fn.dataTable.FixedColumns(oTable);
```

Now the fixed column appears to be a clone of the real column and the clone is displayed over the table making it look fixed.

For this cloned column how can I have a specific class added to each of the rows?

This table is paginated and used server side data for each page.

Comment: did you try addClass() method

Comment: I would try it if I new what to addClass to.

Comment: try with "sClass" in datatable jquery plugin... look at the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using sclass attribute like:

```
 { "mData": "Bound","sClass"="yourClassName" "sTitle": "Bound" }
```

this will add the class attribute to the html code generated by datatable plugin

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks nikhil, your mentioning of "sClass" lead me to the documentation for Columns in Datatables and I used the "aoColumns" property. (http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns) The fact that it's a "fixedcolumn" doesn't appear to make a difference.

Comment: good deal... if you get the solution... you can post the other way also as a next answer... for someone else

Answer (score 1):

Following nikhil's suggestion with "sClass" and the Datatables documentation of ["aoColumns"](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns).

```
 oTable = $('#the-table').dataTable({
     ' aoColumns' : [
           {'sClass' : 'clickable'} // adds css class "clickable" to the first column
       ]
 });
```